# Upload to playstore: ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value

Tags: android, xml, google-play, android-manifest, aapt

**The problem**

I'm trying to upload my application to the google playstore, but i'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value
```

[Click here for an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzo31.png)

**Things that I have tried**

- I only have 1 "strings" folder, so the country issue with different strings folders is not the problem;
- I've generated a launcher icon by: Rightclick Project > new > image asset. So i have 5 sizes of launcher icons in my mipmap folder;
- Cleaned the project
- Moved the app icon to a different folder (drawable);
- tried the `aapt dump badging` command, getting the same vague error;
- Checked all messages by clicking "inspecting code" within android studio;
- i'm not using: android:icon="@android:color/transparent"

**Android manifest**

```xml
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.timgortworst.remindme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="@string/step_detector"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="@string/step_counter"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".BroadcastReceivers.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":remote" />

        <service
            android:name=".Services.AlarmService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".Services.PedometerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

**The question**

How do I fix this problem, so that I can upload the APK to the playstore?

Comment: Have you checked with developer guide;             https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: I think your uses feature tag contains String literals . That rises this issue. I am not sure. Try with Original Content

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem. If you post it as an awnser, I will accept it.